# get json data that have third brackets from url using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to fetch the json data from an url that have following structure

```
[ { "item1": "1", "item2": "2", "item3": "3"}]
```

I am able to find the result  if I remove the third brackets from the above,But i am getting problem to  show  the result because in the url the json data have the above format.

Is it possible to get data from an url that have third brakets?advance thanks

Comment: I can't understand your question. Is that the response data from a request or is it part of the URL?

Comment: What do you mean by _third brackets_? There's one set of square brackets, and one set of curly braces. What's the third one?

Comment: what is `third brakets` here..?

Comment: Well, what I guess is first bracket = ( ), second is { } and the third is [ ].

Comment: @AkiEru wha? There are no parentheses `()` in the question

Comment: I get the above data format from an url,now i have to display the data in my site like -value of item1 is 1    sorry for my bad English

Comment: display on where? js:alert? innerHTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an object inside an array. You can access the properties as:

```
data[0].item1
data[0].item2
data[0].item3
```